# Is there a is_user_logged_in() for multisite?

Tags: multisite, functions, users, login

Is there a is_user_logged_in() function for Wordpress MU / Multisite (3.0+) where I can add in the network site ID like `is_user_logged_in(2)` where `2` would be the site_id?

#### Update:

After a little digging I came up with the code below. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
//don't use this. does not work.
function mu_logged_in($blog_id){
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
        $status = is_user_logged_in();
    restore_current_blog();
    return $status;
}
```

anu's answer and comments are good.

also, make sure you have the cookie domain set correctly in the wp-config.php file :)

Comment: Can you explain the use case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and no!

The way users work in a multisite scenario is that there is a single pool of users, who are then associated with blogs.

So, logged in status is common across all the blogs, but you can use `is_blog_user($blog_id)` to determine whether the **current logged in user** is a member of that blog. An example:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
  if (is_blog_user(4)) echo "Current user is a member of blog 4";
}
```

[Codex page for `is_blog_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/is_blog_user)

Comment: I had something a little different in mind. I've added to to the question, but I think yours is very useful, too.

Comment: Your answer will probably return true for any logged in user, no matter which blog that user is a member of.

Comment: You're right. It still only works for the current blog. But you see what I was trying to get at? I have a blog that the user will not be logged into, but I want to display information if they are logged into a different blog in the network. Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing the point. A user's logged in status is 'global' - ie once that user has logged in, then that user is logged into all blogs with 'subscriber' as the default role.

Comment: actually I had the cookie domain set up wrong. after I fixed that then your code worked very well. thanks!

Comment: Small hint. The function `is_blog_user()` is deprecated and the new functions to get this data is [`is_user_member_of_blog( $user_id, $blog_id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/is_user_member_of_blog).